# jQuery selectors wildcard where not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to figure out how to apply a wildcard concept to something while applying where not.

Right now I have `$('.zm_name[rel!="'+keyed+'"]').parent().hide();` which will hide everything not exactly matching the keyed value I am looking for, this works fine. However it only works when the keyed value is exact. So I am looking to have it so its like `keyed*` but anything not equal to the beginning of the string hide.

I tried `$('.zm_name[rel^!="'+keyed+'"]').parent().hide();` but only get a syntax error, I browsed through the jquery selectors section of the api, and can't seem to find what I am looking for exactly. So I am wondering is there any actual way of combining this method?

Comment: FYI: For all the selectors visit this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.zm_name:not(.zm_name[rel^="'+keyed+'"])').parent().hide();
```

//OR

```
$('.zm_name:not([rel^="'+keyed+'"])').parent().hide();​​​​​​​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FzUsn/)

Comment: What do you mean by `.zm_name:[rel^="'+keyed+'"]`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually stay away from very long selectors because they can be confusing and redundant. Try using the `filter` method:

```
$('.zm_name').filter(function(){ 
  return !(new RegExp('^'+ keyed)).test(this.rel); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe `this.rel` is a bit faster.